# Why is it that adding "z-index: 1;" to the key causes this CSS piano to display incorrectly?

Tags: css

I've been trying to design a piano in CSS. I got it working mostly through a bunch of guessing/checking but don't understand why I had to do what I did to fix it. If I add "z-index: 1;" to the key css the sharp keys no longer overlap the white keys on their right side (even though their z-index is higher). This is not how z-index should work according to every explanation I've read. What exactly is going on here?

```css
* {
        box-sizing: border-box;
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    height:100%;
    width: 100%;
    }

    piano {
        z-index: 0;
        display: flex;
        position: relative;
        background: black;
        padding: 2px;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    key {
        position: relative;
        background: white;
        margin: 2px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    sharp {
        z-index: 2;  
        position: absolute;
        background: black;
        height: 50%;
        width: 50%; 
        right: -25%;
    }
```

```html
<piano>
    <key #c><sharp #cs></sharp></key>
    <key #d><sharp #ds></sharp></key>
    <key #e></key>
    <key #f><sharp #fs></sharp></key>
    <key #g><sharp #gs></sharp></key>
    <key #a><sharp #as></sharp></key>
    <key #b></key>
</piano>
```

Comment: Your sharp elements are inside of your key elements. It's like having a window, the things you see in the window cannot be on top of the window itself. So your sharp inside of the key window cannot be seen from a different window beside it since the stuff in the first window cannot be on top of both windows. Your keys are beside each other so the sharp in window 1 cannot be on top of the key next to it. I hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

### Update

> *"Why is it that when "z-index: 1" is added the rendering fails? Also I think it's quite common to have custom tags when working in React."*

I'll address the second point first. If you use React add the React tag, don't expect anyone to know anything beyond the stated context established by the tags and the question itself.

Second point, I stated:

> *"**Also of note that the stacking order gives higher priority to tags further down the source code**, but in your case shouldn't be a problem since black keys never share the same area with each other."*

This is partly my fault because I glossed over the fact you had said that `z-index: 1` was set to key and the sharp to `z-index: 2`. It's an easy mistake since your code is the correct version not the version you had a question about. Had you added the `z-index: 1` to the key and `z-index: 2` to the sharp, it would've been obvious. What was the purpose of posting an example that doesn't coincide with the question?

So if you have siblings at the same `z-index` the tags that are positioned in the source code lower than it's "older" siblings has a higher stacking priority. (see **Figure III**)

**Figure III**

```html
<div id='A' style='z-index:1'></div>
<div id='B' style='z-index:1'></div><!-- This will overlap anything in #A -->
<div id='C' style='z-index:1'></div><!-- This will overlap anything in #A and #B -->
```

Also, the example has been updated with a switch to demonstrate the problem clearly.

---

If you are using standard HTML (you should unless you are using a HTML preprocessor) that might help. There is no <del>`<piano>`</del>, nor are there any <del>`<key>`</del> or <del>`<sharp>`</del> elements. Use `<div>` and assign them ids and classes. (see **Figure I** & **II**).

**Figure I** - HTML

```html
<div id="piano"><!-- id is unique, there can only be one id="piano" in a page-->
  <div class='c k'><!-- class can be used multiple times on multiple elements -->
    <div class='c s'></div><!-- multiple classes are space separated --> 
  </div>
</div>
```

**Figure II** - CSS

```css
#piano {/*...*/} /* id is prefixed with # */
.k {/*...*/} /* class is prefixed with . */
.s {/*...*/}
```

Can't really tell you exactly what your problem was because you posted the correct way using `z-index`. Note in the example the black keys have `z-index: 1`. (see [*Introducing Z-index"*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Positioning#introducing_z-index))

An element (aka tag) that has `position: absolute` (we will will refer to it as: **posAbs**) will position itself within the perimeter of the closest **pos** ancestor tag. An ancestor tag is a tag containing the tag we are referring to -- that would include any tag higher up the DOM tree. The `z-index` also relates to the closest **pos** ancestor and if none exist then it's the viewport (the entire viewable window of the browser). So if each white key is **posRel** and each black key is **posAbs** with `z-index: 1` or greater will overlap all tags at `index: 0` or less and "static" tags (non-**pos**). Also of note that the stacking order gives higher priority to tags further down the source code, but in your case shouldn't be a problem since black keys never share the same area with each other.

Anyways, the point of this answer is mainly about the use (abuse?) of HTML. HTML is forgiving and will treat non-standard tags as a `<div>`, but as far as how CSS and JavaScript deals with non-standard tags is unpredictable. So if you plan on actually showing your work on different browsers to anyone else in the world, then you should always practice standards.

```js
/* For demonstration purposes only */
let keys = document.querySelectorAll('.k');
let go = document.querySelector('button');
let value = document.querySelector('b');

go.onclick = zIndex;

function zIndex(e) {
  value.classList.toggle('zIndex');
  keys.forEach(key => key.classList.toggle('zIndex'));
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html {
  font: 300 5vmax/1 'Segoe UI'
}

#piano {
  display: flex;
  background: black;
}

.k {
  position: relative;
  z-index: auto;
  width: 0.9rem;
  height: 6rem;
  border: 1px ridge black;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  background: white;
}

.s {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: -2px;
  right: -30%;
  width: 0.6rem;
  height: 3.5rem;
  border: 1px ridge grey;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 2px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 2px;
  background: black;
}

/* For demonstration purposes only */
button {font:inherit;margin-left:20px}
b::before {content:'auto'}
b.zIndex::before {content:'1'}
.k.zIndex {z-index: 1}
```

```html
<div id='piano'>
  <div class='c k'>
    <div class="c s"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='d k'>
    <div class="d s"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='e k'></div>
  <div class='f k'>
    <div class="f s"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='g k'>
    <div class="g s"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='a k'>
    <div class="a s"></div>
  </div>
  <div class='b k'></div>
</div>
<br>
<button>GO</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;<output id='msg'>All white keys <code>index: <b></b></code></output>
```

Comment: I don't think you've answered the question. Your explanation for how z-index works is pretty much exactly what I expected. First of all each black key has a z-index of 2, not 1. According to your explanation (and my understanding) I should be able to assign a z-index of 1 to the white keys because 2 > 1.

My issue isn't with trying to get it to work, the code I have is already working. My issue is with understanding. Why is it that when "z-index: 1" is added the rendering fails?

Also I think it's quite common to have custom tags when working in React.

Comment: See update^^^^^